# High Chart export server is not able to export venn diagram using command

Tags: highcharts

`{ "plotOptions": { "venn": { "borderColor": "transparent" }, "series": { "maxPointWidth": 30 } }, "credits": false, "legend": { "layout": "vertical", "verticalAlign": "middle", "align": "right", "enabled": false }, "series": [{ "type": "venn", "dataLabels": { "enabled": false }, "data": [{ "legendVennDiagram3": ["<span class=\"weight200\"><strong class=\"font-size-1-2em mr10\">15%</strong> IPs WITH MALWRAE INFECTION</span>", "<span class=\"weight200\"><strong class=\"font-size-1-2em mr10\">3%</strong> 3 IPs BLACKLISTED</span>", "<span class=\"weight200\"><strong class=\"font-size-1-2em mr10\">5%</strong> 5 INFECTED WITH CNCs</span>"], "sets": ["A"], "color": "#ffb81c", "vennDiagramSubtitle": "<div class=\"subtitle-venn-chart\"><strong class=\"mr10\">85%</strong> <span class=\"weight200\"> 85 IPS NOT INFECTED</span></div>", "title": "EXTERNAL IP MALWARE INFECTION SUMMARY", "value": 10 }, { "legendVennDiagram3": ["<span class=\"weight200\"><strong class=\"font-size-1-2em mr10\">15%</strong> IPs WITH MALWRAE INFECTION</span>", "<span class=\"weight200\"><strong class=\"font-size-1-2em mr10\">3%</strong> 3 IPs BLACKLISTED</span>", "<span class=\"weight200\"><strong class=\"font-size-1-2em mr10\">5%</strong> 5 INFECTED WITH CNCs</span>"], "sets": ["C"], "color": "#e30000", "vennDiagramSubtitle": "<div class=\"subtitle-venn-chart\"><strong class=\"mr10\">85%</strong> <span class=\"weight200\"> 85 IPS NOT INFECTED</span></div>", "title": "EXTERNAL IP MALWARE INFECTION SUMMARY", "value": 3 }, { "legendVennDiagram3": ["<span class=\"weight200\"><strong class=\"font-size-1-2em mr10\">15%</strong> IPs WITH MALWRAE INFECTION</span>", "<span class=\"weight200\"><strong class=\"font-size-1-2em mr10\">3%</strong> 3 IPs BLACKLISTED</span>", "<span class=\"weight200\"><strong class=\"font-size-1-2em mr10\">5%</strong> 5 INFECTED WITH CNCs</span>"], "sets": ["B"], "color": "#ff8319", "vennDiagramSubtitle": "<div class=\"subtitle-venn-chart\"><strong class=\"mr10\">85%</strong> <span class=\"weight200\"> 85 IPS NOT INFECTED</span></div>", "title": "EXTERNAL IP MALWARE INFECTION SUMMARY", "value": 7 }, { "sets": ["A", "B"], "color": "#ff8319", "value": 6.999 }, { "sets": ["B", "C"], "color": "#e30000", "value": 2.999 } ] } ], "subtitle": { "text": "<div style=\"align: center; border: 2px solid #F2F2F2; padding: 2px 20px;\"><span style><b>85%</b> 85 IPS NOT INFETCED<span></div>", "style": { "color": "#34c52d", "fontWeight": 400 }, "useHTML": true, "align": "center" }, "tooltip": { "enabled": false }, "width": 0, "style": { "height": "300px" }, "title": { "text": "EXTERNAL IP MALWARE INFECTION SUMMARY" }, "plotBorderWidth": 0, "chart": { "type": "venn", "marginLeft": 250 }, "height": 0 }` JSON I am passing to the high-chart server but I am not able to get the Venn diagram in the image.

Shall I have to configure anything in a high-chart server?

Comment: Shall i have to add any configuration to high-chart-server to export venn diagram?

Comment: I tested this configuration configuration here and it works fine:
https://export.highcharts.com/ 

How exactly do you export this chart?